# How to deploy GCP API Gateway and Cloud function together without gcloud commands

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework, google-api-gateway

We built an API and integrated cloud function as backend. Till now we were deploying cloud function first and API gateway later. Is there a best way to club these two services and deploy it as a whole?

Comment: Do you want to deploy them in the same time? To release both exactly in the same time?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes. Wanted to deploy both at the same time as a microservice

Answer (score 1):

It's 2 different products and no, you can't tie them and deploy in the same time.

- Cloud Functions build a container based your code and can take more or less time according to the number of dependencies and the type of language (required compilation (Java or Go) or not).
- API Gateway requires to deploy a new config and to deploy it on a gateway. And it takes a while to achieve these.

So, no link between the product and not the same deployment duration. The right pattern here is to use versioning. You can deploy a service before the others (Cloud Functions before API Gateway) for minor change (doesn't break the existing behavior).

For breaking change, I recommend you to not update the existing functions but to create a new one. The advantage is to have the capacity to continue to have the 2 versions in parallel, and a rapid rollback in case of issue. Same thing for API Gateway, create a new gateway for a new version.